# Looping through a table in python reportlab

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, reportlab

I am creating a table using the python module reportlab. In this table, I would like to loop through and have a different background color depending on the values of any particular cell.

To do this, I came up with the following:

```
elements = []

table1 = [[34,27,35,35],
          [3,76,23,157],
          [13,137,15,75],
          [56,26,46,26]]




t1 = Table(table1)
for ii in range(len(table1)):
    for jj in range(len(table1)):
        if table1[ii][jj] <=50:
            ourcolor = colors.white
        elif table1[ii][jj] <=100:
            ourcolor = colors.skyblue
        elif table1[ii][jj] <=200:
            ourcolor = colors.green

        else:
            ourcolor = colors.white
        t1.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (ii,jj), (ii,jj), ourcolor),
                                ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                                ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                                ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black)
                                ]))

elements.append(t1)
```

But, many of the cells still are not colored and many of them are colored incorrectly, however some of them are correct. I am assuming something is wrong with my loop since I am not a very experienced programmer.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about ReportLab to know for sure, but a common problem in this type of coding is that the axes are swapped.  For example, indexing like this: `table1[ii][jj]` means that `ii` is the y axis (rows) and `jj` is the x axis (columns), so you'd have to supply x and y to ReportLab as `jj, ii`.  Check if your output has rows and columns swapped when coloring cells.

Also, note that your double loop is looping over the same range twice, which works only because your table is square.  If your table even becomes non-square, you'll have the wrong range on one of your loops.

Comment: thanks very much, I also meant to speak about this square problem. I've experienced it when testing with non square tables, but any advice on fixing that? Thanks

Comment: You just need to get the length of the row:  `for jj in range(len(table1[0]))`

Comment: Turns out, all I had to do in the end was switch the jj and ii! thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

It looks like table1 is just a list of lists. I think this code will do what you want it to, assuming the problem lies in your loop and not in the reportlab module (I am not experienced with that).

```
a=-1
for ii in table1:
  a = a+1
  b = -1 
  for jj in ii:
    b = b+1
    if jj <=50:
        ourcolor = colors.white
    elif jj <=100:
        ourcolor = colors.skyblue
    elif jj <=200:
        ourcolor = colors.green
    else:
        ourcolor = colors.white
    t1.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND', (a,b), (a,b), ourcolor),
                              ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                              ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                              ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black)
                              ]))
```

Comment: hmmmm.... when I try this I get an error that says: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list. I'm not sure what the appropriate fix is to this. Could this mean it is a problem with the reportlab module? Thanks

Comment: No, I didn't notice the coordinate system used. In my code, jj points to a list, while in your original, it is an integer because of range (I was wondering why you were using range at all actually). If I'm correct, the first number in the top left is "0,0" right? --> In the context of the coordinate system.

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. The top row of this particular table would be 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3. I guess that's the tricky part about all of this

Comment: Although its not elegant, you can use two variables as counters if you want to use my code. I've edited it in, with a pointing to the x coordinate and b to the y coordinate.

Comment: I have found an easier fix, it turns out all I had to do was swap some x and y values because of the the coordinate system and I have it working now! thanks a lot